# Python 3.3 + pygame installation

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

First, I am aware about the existance of a similar older thread, but honestly, I would not ask, if I found any help there.

Being a simple coding enthusiast, I want to playback media in using python. Since there seems to be no simple solution, a lot of people recommend pygame (or pyglet). So, using win 7 x64, I revert to 32bit Python 3.3.5 and download the presumably correct version of pygame from the super secret download site (pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.3). Both installations work seemingly fine, pygame can locate python (path is set correctly), and finishes its install without issues, yet it seems not to install anything. I cannot import pygame, there are no installed libraries to be found. In pure frustration I tried different iterations of versions, python 2.7, x64, older pygame versions. Nothing worked. I suspect, there is something going on, that may not be connected to the pygame installation, but I don't know what.

```
import pygame
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/***/pygame_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Show your code and full error messages (trackback)

Comment: If you don't know what it is, then there's no way we could possibly know, either...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python 3.2.3 instead of 3.3, along with Pygame for that version: that's what I did, and it works flawlessly on the same system as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You should check up with your installation. Are you sure you installed properly. I have checked on 3.4/3.6/2.7 all works fine. Just install the correct binaries based on your system from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Comment: How does this help the asker?

Answer (score 0):

Download pygame using pip, to be sure that the module is placed in the correct path. Else, put the `pygame` folder in `.\pythonX\Lib\site-packages\`. Verify the folder is named `pygame` and not for example `pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.3`.